# Fortran intermittent type error

Tags: visual-studio-2017, fortran

I was able to temporarily get some legacy Fortran code running (I was able to step through it with the debugger) in Visual Studio 2017 with the Intel Fortran compiler, until it stopped working apparently for no reason.

At the very start I was getting the error below when trying to get the code to run.

```
  error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.
```

That error went away after a post-installation reboot and I was able to test the code for a few weeks, but now it's back.

I don't think I've changed any of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Intel Fortran and it has a feature called "Generated Interface Checking". The way this works is when you compile a source that declares a subroutine or function that isn't in a module, it generates an INTERFACE block and saves a compiled module for it. Then when you compile a source that calls a routine for which you have not provided an explicit interface, it looks to see if there's a generated one and compares it. If you have an argument type mismatch you'll get an error such as this.

However, to work properly the called routine must be compiled before the caller. If this doesn't happen, the interface can't be checked and you'll not get an error. The error is still there, and you may be able to see it if you do a rebuild of the project. Pay attention to the message and fix the problem it describes.  A mismatched argument type is a common cause of run-time errors that come and go.

Comment: Thanks, this answer clued me in to the fact that I could actually step through the code with the debugger all along after the first build.

Comment: Do we think the calculations this code is returning might be corrupted by these argument-type mismatches?

Comment: It is certainly possible.